# Zsh terminal cant see flutter Mac

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello im trying to install Flutter it worked a few days ago, but know the terminal cant find flutter "zsh: command not found: flutter" im thinking i might have to earase all files named flutter and reinstall but not sure how ? ( I have setup vim with the path but it still seems to not being able to find the path ?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNZHe.png)

Many thanks for your time! :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNZHe.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poifv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify how you installed Flutter and how you're having trouble installing it again.  Please include the steps.

Comment: This question is more suited for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: 1) i started by installing flutter from ther website then i

Comment: 2) afterwards i linked it by vim to the path

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the environment path.

1. Open terminal.
2. vim $HOME/.zshrc
3. Press "I" key for going to insert mode.
4. add the following line in the opened file:
   export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"
5. Press "Esc" then write :wq! in terminal and press enter to exit vim.
6. Reopen the terminal and check "flutter doctor"

If this solution did not work, remove the double quote from path or use the full path explicitly instead of ~.

try this steps my issue was solved with this.

Comment: yes ! I have tryid this, it dossnt seem to work when i aftwards try "flutter doctor " it says "zsh: command not found: flutter" ?

Comment: please check flutter installed properly or not.

Comment: as per you attached image remove  flutter from PATH after flutter/bin put path like this (PATH="$PATH:/User/rumlekjaerulso/Development/Tooling/flutter/bin")

Comment: I think it is installed properly bc have all the files in the folder ?

Comment: yea i just tryid to remove flutter from the vim it still dossnt work :(

Comment: I just oploaded a new picture of my VIM

Comment: you created Development folder in your user?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).